# How to add a presentation variable in the logical sql in obiee 11g

Tags: obiee

I make a dashboardprompt and I want to make a default selection starting from an logical sql. In th options I choose as default selection "SQL Results". In my query I want to put a filter with a presentation variable. I thought to use this query:

```
SELECT "Human Resources - Talent Profile Management"."Basic Information"."Person Number" 
FROM "Human Resources - Talent Profile Management"
WHERE
("Position"."Position Identifier" = '@{P_pos_id}{9900574}')
```

But I don't know how to put the presentation variable. Like this code, it does not work.

Comment: Why this convoluted approach? 9 times out of 10 it's simply a wrong way of handling things and easily done with out-of-the-box functionality. What's the goal?

Comment: I have two prompts. When I select in the first prompt (with presentation varable P_pos_id) a position identifier, I want the second prompt to be default selected by this query above. I don't want to filter the second prompt, I just want to change the selection, but I want to be able to select other things too.

Comment: So what's your problem? The approach will work. Technicallt that's valid. Are you using two distinct prompt objects or just two columns in one prompt?

Comment: two distinct prompts. The first time it works now, but when I change one prompt, the second prompt does not change

Comment: Auto-applying prompts or ones with buttons for explicit execution?